# Finding your colcon built workspace's lib path using ros2

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was wondering if there was an equivalent to ```catkin_find --lib --include`` in ros2.

I need this information to create a non ros package that includes ros publishers and subscribers.

Currently, I am using a workaround which is to use `ros2 pkg prefix foo` to find the messages created by the workspace and then move my way up the folders using ../.

I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this.

Also, if it is not to much trouble, cmake_ament no longer uses pkg-config to find packages.
How can I add my workspace's libraries to the CMakelist? This is for the case of custom msgs and services.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313609/finding-your-colcon-built-workspace%27s-lib-path-using-ros2/) by [Obeseturtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39489/obeseturtle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 185 on 2019-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I am using a workaround which is to use `ros2 pkg prefix foo` to find the messages created by the workspace and then move my way up the folders using ../.

Why do you have to move up in this case?

The command will return the install prefix of the package `foo`. All files installed by that package will be in subdirectories, e.g. `bin`, `include`, `lib`, `share`.

If you need `pkg-config` like results you can invoke `cmake --find-package ...` to get information about include directories, libraries etc. (see [Find-Package Tool Mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/manual/cmake.1.html#find-package-tool-mode)).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Obeseturtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39489/obeseturtle/) on 2019-01-24**:
Thank you very much for your response.

> Why do you have to move up in this case?

This was just a mistake on my part.

As you mentioned the include, lib. and shared could be found by using the prefix command.
I will try using the suggested `cmake --find-package`  command. Thank you again